# How can I stop Outlook offering my images as attachments?

Tags: email, outlook

I have a system that automatically sends emails to people which include images.  All the recipients are known to use Outlook 2003.  I am doing this by attaching the images to the email and then referencing the images with `img` tags in the messages.

This works, but I want to stop Outlook from displaying the attached images as normal attachments at the top of the viewer.  There can be many of them and they clutter up the view.  Is there a way to do this?  I don't have control of the Outlook clients, just my system that's sending the emails.

I have tried dropping the attachment idea and using embedded encoded data in the html but Outlook's html renderer isn't able to understand this.  I have considered dropping the attachment idea and serving the images from another location but this isn't possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a solution, *per se*, but a strategy for figuring it out.)

1. Paste an image into an Outlook email and send it to a Gmail account.
2. Use Gmail to view the raw email (The drop-down menu at the far right has a "Show Original" option).
3. Compare this to the emails you are generating and see if you can spot the difference.

Outlook might have an option to view the raw email too. I just can't find it.